# cannot use setState in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have the below component and every time I try to use the `setState` function I get the warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. 
This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op. Please check the code for the LoginView component
```

I have tried adding `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` for debugging this only and while inside the `this.setState` callback the state is updated and I get `mounted` as true, when I try to type in my input `onInputChange` `this.state.mounted` is still false and won't update the state...

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong because I am trying to follow examples online.

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import BaseComponent from 'BaseComponent';
import * as loginActions from './LoginActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const LOGIN_ACTIONS = loginActions.LOGIN_ACTIONS

class LoginView  extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.props = props;
    this.setupState.bind(this);
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.state = this.setupState();
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    this.render = this.render.bind(this);

  }

  setupState (){
    debugger;
    return {
      mounted: false,
      fields : {
        email: '',
        password:'',
      },
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    debugger;
    this.setState({ mounted: true }, function() {
      debugger;
      console.log(this);
    }.bind(this));

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    debugger;
    this.setState({ mounted: false })

  }

  onInputChange(evt){
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
    if(this.state.mounted){
      this.setState({fields : fields});
    }
     // this.state.fields = fields;
  }

  submitForm(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    //debugger;
    //this.actions.login(this.state.fields.email, this.state.fields.password);
  }


  render() {

        return (
            <div>

                    <h1>Swirl Simulator Manager</h1>
                    <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                        <label>Username</label>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Email'
              name='email'
              value={this.state.fields.email}
              onChange={this.onInputChange} />
            <br />
                        <label>Password</label><input type='password'name='password' value={this.state.fields.password} onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" />
                    </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default connect(
  state => { return { auth: state.auth }; },
  dispatch => { return { actions: bindActionCreators(loginActions, dispatch) }; }
)(LoginView);
```

### UPDATE:

I was able to get it to work by binding this in the render function like follows:

```
 <input type='text' placeholder='Email'
              name='email'
              value={this.state.fields.email}
              onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} />
```

but I don't understand why this works and `this.onInputChange.bind(this)` in the constructor doesn't

I also tried using the arrow function:

```
onInputChange = (evt) => {
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
      this.setState({fields : fields}, ()=> {
        console.log(this.state);
      });
  }
```

and this results in the same issue as if done in the constructor

### UPDATE 2 - updated code to exclude componentWillMount

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

export default class LoginView  extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fields : {
      email: '',
      password:'',
    },
  };
  constructor(props){
    debugger;
    super(props);

    //this.props = props;
    //this.setupState.bind(this);
    //this.render = this.render.bind(this);

    // This doesn't allow me to set state in onInputChange
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);


  }

  onInputChange(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({fields : fields}, ()=> {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }

  /*  This also does not allow me to setState
  onInputChange = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({fields : fields}, ()=> {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }
  */

  submitForm(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }


  render() {

        return (
        <div>

            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Email'
                       name='email'
                       value={this.state.fields.email}
                       onChange={this.onInputChange} />
                <br />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type='password'
                       name='password' 
                       value={this.state.fields.password} 
                       onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If I change the input on the password field everything works as expected, but never on the email if I use the constructor to bind this or if I use the Arrow function (both commented out above)

just in case this is somehow caused by webpack here is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].bundle.css')

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: {
    'app' : [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './App.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            //'es2017',
            'es2016',
            "stage-0",
            "react"
          ],
          plugins:[
            'react-hot-loader/babel'
          ]
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      loader: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader','sass-loader'])
    }]
  }, // End : module
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    extractCSS,
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      BaseComponent$ : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/BaseComponent.js'),
      'views' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/views'),
      'modules' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/modules'),
      'services' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/services')
    }
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

and my Dependiences

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "0.27.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.3",
    "webpack": "2.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "0.27.3",
    "node-sass": "4.5.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-redux": "5.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "4.0.0",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.16.0"
  }
```

Comment: remove `this.state.mounted` completely. There is absolutely no need for you to track that. You need to `bind` only functions that are passed as props to child components. Don't bind any other functions.

Comment: @Sultan I was only tracking mounted to try to debug this. I removed all the binds except for `onInputChange` because it was was complaining of state being undefined and I still get the above warning....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but do these changes they are not required, may be it will solve your issue:

**1.** Remove these lines:

```
this.props = props;
this.setupState.bind(this);
this.render = this.render.bind(this);  //binding of render method is not required
```

**2.** Remove the `setState` from `componentWillUnmount` method, because after `setState`, `React` will try to do the `re-rendering`.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    debugger;
   // this.setState({ mounted: false })
}
```

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount):

> componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is
>   unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method,
>   such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests.

Comment: Still doesn't solve my problem, still getting the warning error and my state is not updated on keying in to input fields

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would you like to keep track of mounted or unmounted states in your component.  The source of the problem is basically this:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ mounted: false })
  }
```

Makes no sense to try to set the state of a component that will inevitable be unmounted by react, so you get a warning that what you're doing is basically `no-op` (No operation) and has no effect. I strongly advice you to read a [component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) and clarify what you meant

Comment: I was only doing it for debugging this, that does not resolve my problem, the problem happens in `onInputChange`